# Namespacing imported assets

Tags: asset

I'm looking at pipelining Blender and I'm wondering about namespacing.

It seems that Blender is pretty strict about node names and that no two geo/transform nodes in a scene can have the same name. If that's the case, it seems like there should be a formal way to namespace hierarchies of nodes (like Maya allows by prefixing "< N A M E S P A C E >:")

Currently if I import the same model asset twice, Blender just renames all nodes for the second import with a ".001" postfix.

Does anyone know how this is intended to be handled?

Thanks in advance

In response to vklidu's request for more info; indeed blender is adding the ".001" postfix to make the objects unique, which makes sense. However it would be preferable to have formal control over the renaming, ideally at the point of import.

Maya's namespacing is formalised, in that you can pass the namespace you want to use at the point of import. So in our pipeline we might import the exact same rig file multiple times (e.g. "Soldier" asset). We assign each one a "cast member name" ("Soldier_1", "Soldier_2" etc.) and use those as namespaces. This will prefix each object in the imported hierarchy with "Soldier_1:".

It just means everything is named uniquely but also predictably. Right now I'm just doing the Blender import and renaming programmatically with a similar type of "cast member name" prefix after the fact, which is fine. I just thought I'd sanity check it here, see if there's anything I'm missing, what other studios are doing etc.

Comment: Your Q is probably confusing in name convention for blender user. When I went to search Maya's prefix ":" I found [this article](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/maya-namespace-and-prefix-tips-and-tricks.html) -namespacing doesn't seem to be  useful at some point ... blender's .001 suffix is simply to distinguish objects (make unique) ... so I think I didn't get your goal here - what are you looking for? Do you need a name of source file be a part of imported object's name as prefix? Thanks for some details (if none answer here).

Comment: there are renaming tools like this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvp9Y.png maybe this helps you? you can find it by search "batch rename"

Comment: in response to vklidu (I'm not permitted to comment yet); indeed blender is adding the ".001" postfix to make the objects unique, which makes sense. However it would be preferable to have formal control over the renaming, ideally at the point of import. Maya's namespacing is formalised, in that you can pass the namespace you want to use at the point of import. So in our pipeline we might import the exact same rig file multiple times (e.g. "Soldier" asset). We assign each one a "cast member name" ("Soldier_1", "Soldier_2" etc.) and use those as namespaces. This will prefix each object in the im

Comment: Thanks for edit ... You can delete comment above (partly copying extended Q) if you have privilege ... Sadly I haven't heard about such feature even used by some studio (with their own build version) ... But it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. It seems Chris's suggestion with Batch Rename is a way or store versions in Collections, but right it is just an organizer.